# LONGTEXT valid in migration for PGSQL and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am developing a Ruby on Rails application that stores a lot of text in a LONGTEXT column. I noticed that when deployed to Heroku (which uses PostgreSQL) I am getting insert exceptions due to two of the column sizes being too large. Is there something special that must be done in order to get a tagged large text column type in PostgreSQL?

These were defined as "string" datatype in the Rails migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the longtext datatype in PostgreSQL as well, just create it. A [domain](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createdomain.html) will do:

```
CREATE DOMAIN longtext AS text;

CREATE TABLE foo(bar longtext);
```

Comment: I will take a look to see what Rails is binding it to, but my guess is that merely using "text" as the column type, or overriding it, will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL the required type is `text`. See the [Character Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-character.html) section of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

A new migration that updates the models datatype to 'text' should do the work. Don't forget to restart the database. if you still have problems, take a look at your model with 'heroku console' and just enter the modelname.

If the db restart won't fix the problem, the only way I figured out was to reset the database with 'heroku pg:reset'. No funny way if you already have important data in your database.